# Number of rows locked in mysql query

Tags: mysql

Is there a way in mysql that I can find the number of rows that get locked when a certain query runs? Eg. for a query, what is the number of rows locked:-

```
UPDATE xyz SET ARCHIVE = 1 , LAST_MODIFIED = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE ID = '123' AND ARCHIVE = 0;
```

Assume in this case, there is a index on ID and Archive is part of primary key.

Answer (score 1):

```
BEGIN;

# lock
UPDATE xyz SET ARCHIVE = 1 , LAST_MODIFIED = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE ID = '123' AND ARCHIVE = 0;

# returns locked rows (X)
SELECT trx_rows_locked FROM information_schema.innodb_trx;

# release
COMMIT;
```